# How to map a custom file extension to mono?

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, mod-mono

I have mapped *.xyz extension to my own custom handler in asp.net and can run it on Windows asp.net.

**How can I do the same thing on mono (Linux/Apache - ubuntu)?**

I have this in my web.config:

```
<httpHandlers><add path="*.xyz" verb="*" type="MyCustomHandler,...">...
```

I also added similar things to `mod_mono.conf` and several other files but still I get

> http 404 The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [AutoConfiguration](http://www.mono-project.com/AutoHosting) enabled then you need to add:

```
AddType application/x-asp-net .m
```

to mod_mono.conf, where .m is your custom extension.

If you have AutoConfiguartion disabled the you need to add:

```
AddHandler mono .m
```

to your httpd.conf.